# Applying function (which takes two arguments) to two columns of DataFrame at once

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How do I use the function shown below on two columns element-wise of my dataframe given that the function takes two arguments? Each row of my dataframe is in a List format already with the same number of elements in each column; I just need help applying this function. I already attempted the .apply() method but was unable to succeed. Thank you very much.

```
def tagged(word, tag):
   final = [x + '|' + y for x in word for y in tag]
   return final


#testing method:
tagged(['a', 'b'], ['1', '2'])

#Output:
['a|1','a|2','a|3','a|4','b|1','b|2','b|3','b|4','c|1','c|2']

#Sample of my Dataframe
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'text':['I','am'], 'tag': ['PRN','ADJ']})
```

Comment: Can you post a small sample of your dataframe, along with a desired output?  It looks like you want to use `zip`

Comment: I posted a sample of my dataframe. The desired output is essentially a new column in which each element is "word|tag"

Comment: No, not as an image, as text in your question.  Output should be the same way.  See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Comment: Sorry about that; I posted the text @user3483203

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
>>> df['result'] = [tagged(w, t) for w, t in df[['word col', 'tag col']].values)]
```